# CZMQ : Unable to receive message

Tags: zeromq

I am trying to write a simple program to demonstrate Publisher/Subscriber communication using 'libczmq'. Although I am able to send the message via the 'zmsg_send' api ( or so I presume based on its return value ), I am unable to receive the message via the 'zmsg_recv' (blocking) API, it is probably unable to receive the message.

```
#include "czmq.h"
int main (void)
{
  int rc;
  const char *ipc_file="ipc://tmp.socket";
  const char *str = "Hello World!!!";

  /*****************************************/
  /* Creating and binding publisher Socket */
  /*****************************************/
  zsock_t *pub_sock = zsock_new(ZMQ_PUB);
  assert(pub_sock!=NULL);
  rc = zsock_bind(pub_sock, ipc_file, NULL);
  assert(rc==0);

  /**************************************************/
  /* Creating and connecting with Subscriber Socket */
  /**************************************************/
  zsock_t *sub_sock = zsock_new(ZMQ_SUB);
  assert(sub_sock);
  rc = zsock_connect(sub_sock, ipc_file, NULL);
  assert(rc==0);

  /***************************************/
  /* Creating messager & Frame instances */
  /*         and sending message         */
  /***************************************/
  zmsg_t *msg = zmsg_new ();
  assert(msg!=NULL);
  zframe_t *frame = zframe_new (str, strlen(str));
  assert(frame!=NULL);
  zmsg_prepend(msg, &frame);
  printf("PUB : frame_count = %u, content_size = %d, msg_ptr = %p\n",
        zmsg_size (msg), zmsg_content_size(msg), msg);
  rc = zmsg_send(&msg, pub_sock);
  assert (rc == 0);
  printf("PUB : Message send successfully...\n");

  /********************************/
  /* Subscriber receiving message */
  /********************************/
  printf("SUB : Reading message...\n");
  msg = zmsg_recv(sub_sock);
  assert(msg!=NULL);
  printf("SUB : frame_count = %u, content_size = %d, msg_ptr = %p\n",
        zmsg_size (msg), zmsg_content_size(msg), msg);
  frame = zmsg_pop(msg);
  assert(frame!=NULL);
  printf("SUB : received in frame = \"%s\"\n", zframe_data (frame));

  zmsg_destroy (&msg);
  zframe_destroy (&frame);
  zsock_destroy (&sub_sock);
  zsock_destroy (&pub_sock);
  return 0;
}
```

Below is how I built and executed the application.

```
user@debian:~/progs/czmq$ make
cc -Iczmq/include -ggdb   -c -o pub-sub-test.o pub-sub-test.c
gcc -L./czmq/src/.libs -lzmq -lczmq -lpthread pub-sub-test.o -o ../pub-sub-test
user@debian:~/progs/czmq$ ../pub-sub-test
PUB : frame_count = 1, content_size = 14, msg_ptr = 0x1653b10
PUB : Message send successfully...
SUB : Reading message...
```

The 'message' is never read by the subscriber, please let me know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there is no subscription on a SUB socket. Try using the variant that takes a subscription :

```
zsock_t* zsock_new_sub (const char *endpoints, const char *subscribe)
```

Or create the subscription after :

```
zsock_set_subscribe (void *zsock, const char *subscribe);
```

The empty string subscribes to everything.

Comment: The zmq handle ( of type void* ) is encapsulated within the 'zsock_t' structure  we do not have access to the same, hence the usage of 'zmq_setsockopt' is out of question. Please refer to the below code
https://github.com/zeromq/czmq/blob/master/src/zsock.c

Here I am trying to use the czmq ( c bindings for zmq ), where the 'plain old ZMQ' artifacts are encapsulated within the 'czmq' types.

Comment: Updated answer to be more czmq specific

Comment: Thanks for the correction, It works now, the problem was definitely the absence of 'zsock_set_subscribe' as you pointed out. In addition to this there was another problem. The publisher used to send the message before the subscriber had an opportunity to connect, hence the message would be lost, the subscriber would continue to wait for a message which would never come.

Initializing the subscriber before the publisher and adding a small delay (say 1 sec) immediately after the publisher's initialization would give enough time for the subscriber to connect and eventually receive the message.

Answer (score 0):

There two problems in the above program.

1. The absence of 'zsock_set_subscribe' as @david points out in an earlier comment.
2. The publisher sends the message before subscriber has an opportunity to connect, hence the message would be lost and the subscriber would continue to wait for a message which would never come.

Solution :

1. Adding the 'zsock_set_subscribe' after the subscriber socket is
   initialized.
2. Initializing the subscriber before the publisher and
   adding a small delay (say 1 sec) immediately after the publisher' so
   as to  provide enough time for the subscriber to connect and
   eventually receive the message.